# Avoiding circular references: forward declaration isn't valid if I need objets's methods?

Tags: circular-dependency

I have a large project, and I got myself into a circular reference I don't know how to fix. I have read about forward declarations, but if I have understood well, that object's public methods/data aren't public if i use forward declaration.

I understand that best way to fix this is to design the program right from its very first lines of code, but sometimes you inherit a large code which carries these kind of problems and to add a simple feature to the code you find yourself into a mess.

So... is there any other way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where class A uses a class B but none of it's methods, class A can forward declare class B. If class B uses class A, then the forward declaration will remove half of the cyclic dependency, at least as far as the compiler is concerned.

If A needs more intimate knowledge of B than just its name, you could use an interface (abstract class) to invert the dependency from A to B. I.e. A uses a new C (instead of B) which exports at least the interface that A requires, and B implements/extends C.

I've seen this used mostly to reduce compilation times - is this your reason for asking, or is it more to do with "good" design?

Comment: It has more yo do with "good" design, yes. Is that the reason why abstract classes exist? I guess I should leanr more about this topic. Could you explain me how to use this to solve a cyclic dependency?